# Minecraft 1.9.2: Ender chest disappearing in End after death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have this recurrent problem. Each time I die in the End, the Ender chest I placed in it disappears, which is very annoying.

Is it a bug? Is it because the enderdragon destroys it every time?

I am on Lubuntu 15.10, if it helps in any way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every time you enter The End the obsidian platform is regenerated and three high space above it is cleared from any blocks. If you placed the chest directly on the obsidian platform, it would be deleted.

If the disappearing chest is somewhere else in The End you might be experiencing a very weird and oddly specific glitch, which is unlikely. The dragon doesn't move while you are not in The End, so it won't be destroying the chest without you being able to witness it.

Comment: ok, I did place it on the obsidian platform! Thx for the info. And if I place it on a block adjacent to the platform, it then shouldn't disappear, right?

Comment: As long as it's not on or above the obsidian,  yes